# Exam subject GRE 0568 Q23.

Tags: calculus, gre-exam

The question and the answer is written below:[image]
[image]

I wonder why the author said "To be tangent, we also need $f(x_{0})=g(x_{0})$", could anyone help me?

Comment: For two curves to be tangent at some point, they actually have to touch at some point, in addition to having the same slope there. This is what the author is saying: $ f(x_0) = g(x_0) $ is the condition that the two curves are actually touching at the x-coordinate for which they have the same slope.

Comment: yeah ..... thank you :)